# Let $\psi:\mathbb{Z} \to R$ be the ring homomorphism that takes $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ to the $k$-fold sum of $1$ or $-1.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $\psi:\mathbb{Z} \to R$ be the ring homomorphism that takes $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ to the $k$-fold sum of $1$ or $-1.$

How do I write out this homomorphism explictly? I am a little confused on the wording of "$k$-fold sum of $1$ or $-1$." My attempt: If $a \in R$ then the map is defined as:

$k \mapsto 
  \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \sum a & : a > 0 \\
       \sum -a & : a < 0 
     \end{array}
   \right.$

Comment: $\psi(k)=k \cdot 1_R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're a fan of the sigma sum notation, a correct way to write it would be
$$k\mapsto \left\{\begin{array}{ll}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{k}{1_R}&\mbox{ if }k\geq 0\\\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{-k}{-1_R}&\mbox{ if }k<0\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: @Shalop note in that case $k$ is negative, so I really do mean $-k$.

Comment: Thank you, although I'm not necessarily a fan of the sigma sum notation, I just migrated to it. Would $k \mapsto k$ if $k \geqslant 0$ and $k \mapsto -k$ if $k < 0$ also work?

Comment: @StVincent No. That's the point, $k$ and $-k$ need not be elements of the ring, so you're defining the image of $k$ as a sum of $1$ or $-1$ with itself $|k|$ times.

Comment: As Shalop said, the easy way to write this is $k\mapsto k\cdot 1$, where $1$ is the $1$ in $R$ and $k\cdot r$ for $k\in \mathbb Z$, $r\in R$ is defined as iterated addition of $r$ or $-r$.

Comment: I suggest to replace $k<0$ by $k \leq 0$ for aesthetical (and other, more involved) reasons.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Personally, I like my case list to be mutually exclusive, so I think I'm going to keep it this way. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is an abelian group, then it carries a unique [$\mathbb{Z}$-module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_%28mathematics%29) structure. In fact, we define $z \cdot a \in A$ for $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a \in A$ by recursion:
$$0 \cdot a := 0$$
$$(z+1) \cdot a := z \cdot a + a$$
$$(z-1) \cdot a := z \cdot a - a$$
Notice that $\mathbb{Z} \to A$, $z \mapsto z \cdot a$ is a homomorphism for fixed $a \in A$.

Using this definition, we can make sense of $z \cdot 1_R \in R$ where $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $1_R$ is the unit of a ring $R$. Then $\mathbb{Z} \to R$, $z \mapsto z \cdot 1_R$ is a ring homomorphism. In fact, it is additive by the discussion above, and multiplicativity follows by induction and $1_R \cdot 1_R = 1_R$.

By the way, this is the *unique* homomorphism of rings $\mathbb{Z} \to R$, expressing that $\mathbb{Z}$ is an *[initial object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_and_terminal_objects)* of $\mathsf{Ring}$.